# how to install local package in R

Tags: r, package

I have made a local R package in a project and now I want to install it.

My working directory is this:
    getwd()
    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQXEr.png) "C:/Users/wo2/RSSCPM"

I check the package and there is no problem. I want to install the package to my .libpath, but R studio chooses a different libpath than i see under tools. 
[image: The library i want to install package to]

How do i get R to install the package in the correct directory?

Comment: Well as it says there, you don't have permissions to write to that directory. Try as administrator maybe?

Comment: something has happend from R 3.6.2 to R 4.0.0. .. i am administrator, but my R installation does not work what so ever after this upgrade.. it was impossible to update packages.. i had to create a new directory.. now i cannot install my own packages...

Comment: Did you try doing a fresh reinstall? Sounds like something got messed up. Were you able to install packages to this path in the past?

Comment: I am on my 100 restart and 3. reinstallation..... everything worked in 3.6.2 .. i have done loads of upgrades.. litterally nothing works now...

Comment: What does it say when you try to upgrade packages? Do you get the same error (`Error no permission to install to directory....`)?

Comment: update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt=TRUE)      i am using this command... but it stops.. nothing happens.. R studio becomes idle (for 4hours before i stopped it)..

Comment: Have you tried without `checkBuilt = TRUE`?

Comment: Have you read the detailed information provided with the documentation about upgrading from  R 3.X to 4.0 ?   And have you checked with RStudio to see if there's a revision to be compatible with 4.0?   And, finally,  if you run R CMD  from a terminal window, can you install ?

Comment: Gents, I thanks for your suggestions... i have found the reason.... there are areas on my computer that are outside my control... its a VIRUS... who would have thought..  i have been hacked!